# How to edit a tab bar view container's height in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

So on my page. I've created a tab bar view that shows data. I've got two containers below each tab. You can see the containers in figure 1 and figure 2 below the first tab.
I'm having a slight issue, I don't how to write the code for the height of the container in the tab bar view. If I give the container a height of double.maxFinite, it just scrolls endlessly (figure 3), if I give the container a constant height, only a portion of the screen will display the data (figure 4). How should I write my code so the two sub-containers containing the data will scroll and stop once we can view the bottom of the second container (as seen in image 5). Note - I want the containers to scroll under historical and projected data

```
    return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    labelColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                        letterSpacing: -1,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                    indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'historical data'),
                      Tab(text: 'projected data'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200, //////////////// HEIGHT ISSUE HERE
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: [
                      //first tab
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                        // column and containers
                      ),
                      //second tab
                      SingleChildScrollView(
                        // column and containers
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl73u.png)

NEW CODE EDITED BELOW

```
class _TotalPopulationPageState
extends State<TotalPopulationDataTableAndChartsPage>
with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

static final List historicaltotalpopulationlData =

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
TabController _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          labelColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              letterSpacing: -1,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
          indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'historical data'),
            Tab(text: 'projected data'),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              //first tab
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      BarChartBox(
                        title: 'historical total population data chart',
                        height: 270,
                        barchart: charts.BarChart(
                          historicaldata,
                          animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          vertical: false,
                          domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                            renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                              labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                                    Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                            renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                              labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                                    Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      DataTableBox(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'historical total population data table',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    letterSpacing: -1,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2020',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '206,139,589',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2015',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '181,137,448',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2010',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '158,503,197',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2005',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '138,865,016',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2000',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '122,283,850',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1995',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '107,948,335',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1990',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '95,212,450',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1985',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '83,562,785',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1980',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '73,423,633',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1975',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '63,374,298',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1970',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '55,982,144',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1965',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '50,127,921',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '1960',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '45,138,458',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //second tab
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      BarChartBox(
                        title: 'projected total population data chart',
                        height: 270,
                        barchart: charts.BarChart(
                          projecteddata,
                          animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          vertical: false,
                          domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                            renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                              labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                                    Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                            renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                              labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                                    Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      DataTableBox(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'projected total population data table',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                                    height: 1.2,
                                    letterSpacing: -1,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2080',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '620,456,675',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2075',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '586,202,598',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2070',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '550,374,955',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2065',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '513,527,738',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2060',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '476,130,398',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2055',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '438,639,114',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2050',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '401,315,000',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2045',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '364,711,807',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2040',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '329,066,615',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2035',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '294,986,051',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2030',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '262,977,337',
                          ),
                          DemographicsCard(
                            year: '2025',
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                            figure: '233,343,112',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: No-one wants to look at a code block that large. Please narrow it down to the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: code shortened @hacker1024

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried using `MainAxisSize.min` in your columns?

Comment: @hacker1024  tried it didn't work. please check my code and images. there is a container around the tab bar view. inside this container is the historical and projected data tab text and the container below them. the issue I'm having is what height should I give this invisible container.

Answer (score 0):

First if the content inside is scrollable please temove the top most singlechildscrollview. You can try this structure

Container of height and width as device -> Column -> tab bar and Expanded. Inside expanded -> Tabbarview

Comment: I followed your instructions but still didn't work. I've posted the code directly below my previous one. Please disregard the length of code. the part I have issues with is just at the top

Comment: Whats the error now?

Comment: there is no error now. i have two containers under each tabs. the second container just scrolls and stops halfway. the problem is still with the size of the container that holds everything. it needs a height that allows the user to scroll all the sub containers in the tab completely.

Comment: Please wrap the SingleChildScrollView with an expanded widget. Your layout looks good to me

Comment: still didn't work. are we missing something

Comment: Can you include a minimal code so i can reproduce the behaviour please?

Comment: posted the new code. the code shows all the content in the tab bar class. please remember, there is a separate set of code that shows the top image. the population title and the population counter. i didn't post the code because its too long. please refer to the pictures I posted so you can see. thanks a lot